# Solving inequality(limit)

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]
[image]

Can someone explain how we get from $(x - 3) < \varepsilon/8$ and $x < 4$ to: $(x-3)(x+3) < (\varepsilon/8)(4+3) = (7\varepsilon)/8$

Comment: I think you are missing a part of the problem/solution. Can you post the entire problem and solution?

Comment: @wythagoras its about proving that the limit is 9 when x->3, i'll post more of the problem

Comment: Also the problem, please.

Comment: @wythagoras posted everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I will explain something more, because it is poorly explained in the example.

Note that $|x-3|<\delta$ (by the epsilon-delta definition).

As in your example, we want $\delta < \varepsilon/8$.

Now we also want that $\delta < 1$, so we take $\delta = \min\{\varepsilon/8, 1\}$.

Now we have $x-3<|x-3|<\delta<1$, so $x-3<1$, so $x<4$ and $x+3<7$.

Therefore $x^2-9= (x-3)(x+3) < \delta \cdot 7 < \varepsilon/8 \cdot 7 < \frac{7\varepsilon}{8}$

If there are still questions, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

if $0<a<A$ and $0<b < B$ then $ab < AB$.

Since $x-3 < e/8$ and $x<4$ (so $x+3 < 4+3 = 7$)

$(x-3)(x+3) < (e/8) \cdot 7$

Comment: i'm afraid i still don't understand. "if 0<a<A and 0<b<B then ab<AB." With that in mind shouldn't x(x-3)< (e*4)/8